# Golang http.HandlerFunc closures initialization

Tags: http, go, closures, httphandler

Matt Ryer mentioned something interesting in his talk [How I Write HTTP Web Services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWBSMsLG8po&feature=emb_logo). He proposed writing http handlers that return a handlerfunc like this:

```
func (s *server) handleSomething() http.HandlerFunc {
  thing := prepareThing()
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // use thing
  }
}
```

This allows you to pass arguments, or use a server db connection in the handler through closures without having global variables.

My question is if `prepareThing()` is being executed after every request, or on application startup. He mentioned loading templates or doing other expensive setup in the `prepareThing()` closure. Does this mean that the closure is only executed on app startup? Why is this?

Comment: Why is `handleSomething` only executed at startup? Because you only call it at startup. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: There is no magic: the scope of the variable `thing` is the body of the outer handler; so it's re-assigned a new value each time that outer handler is executed.

Comment: So I can do expensive setup inside the closure instead of in a main.go setup function?

Comment: May be your mental struggle is that `handleSomething()` is actually a _factory method:_ something you call to get an actual "HTTP request handler", and _that one_ is a thing which is to be hooked into an HTTP serve mux to serve particular requests—and hence to be called for each of them. Is is clearer now?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. So the router is only using the return method of handleSomething(). Thanks.

Comment: «So I can do expensive setup inside the closure…?»—In your example the closure is what the `return` statement returns: this is a so-called function literal, and in Go, function literals can close over variables in outer lexical scopes, with `thing` being such variable. The setup (which, I assume, is what `prepareThing` does) is not done in the closure—it's done in `handleSomething`.

Comment: To be honest, I do not see any sense in using the approach you're struggling with: it's simple to declare a `struct` type implementing one or more methods having the `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` signature, explicitly create one or more values of this type and then hook them into the mux. That'd be more text but way less cognitive burden. To put it another way, the code from your example would unlikely pass my review (I do them).

Comment: …that is, do not forget that a closure is a value of bespoke type—created behind your back by the compiler when it saw that the function literal closes over at least a single variable—and a method on it, which is the function literal turned into a closure. Sometimes, closures indeed are a perfect fit for a task; here—I'm not that sure ;-)

Comment: Maybe this practical example helps you understand; only the "closure" that is returned is invoked on every request. Everything before that, only when you call the "factory" func - `handleSomething`. https://play.golang.org/p/KdnWeBFmuTW